# react native firebase analytics purchase event item quantity always set to 0 - tracking event in debug view

Tags: react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase, product-quantity

I am using react-native-firebase for google analytics and when I check Eccomerce purchases report on google analytics dashboard, there is no data for "item purchase quantity" and "item revenue", its always 0.

[image: google analytics report]

I was tracking purchase event in debug view and saw that item quantity is always set to 0.

[image: debug view item data]

This is code I use to log purchase event:

```
const data = {
             transaction_id: 'T_12345',
             value: 1.50,
             currency: 'USD',
             tax: 0,
             shipping: 0,
             coupon: 'free_shipping',
             items: [{
                     item_id: 'I_12345',
                     item_name: 'TEST',
                     item_list_name: 'TEST_L',
                     item_list_id: 'L_12345',
                     item_brand: 'TEST_B',
                     item_category: 'TEST_C',
                     item_variant: 'TEST_V',
                     quantity: 1,
                     price: 1,
                     }]
               }
                    
await analytics().logEvent('purchase', data)
```

I get this output log in xcode:

[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event

```
params: purchase, {
coupon = free_shipping;
currency = USD;
ga_conversion (_c) = 1;
ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
ga_event_origin (_o) = app;
ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
ga_screen (_sn) = Cart Order;
ga_screen_class (_sc) = Cart Order;
ga_screen_id (_si) = -2307947086818646522;
items = (
{
"item_brand" = "TEST_B";
"item_category" = "TEST_C";
"item_id" = "I_12345";
"item_list_id" = "L_12345";
"item_list_name" = "TEST_L";
"item_name" = TEST;
"item_variant" = "TEST_V";
price = 1;
quantity = 1;
}
);
shipping = 0;
tax = 0;
transaction_id = T_12345;
value = 1.5;
}
```

...but in firebase debug view showing 0.

How to pass item quantity data correctly?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, but i needed to change react native firebase library, to modify params NSDictionary in RNFBAnalyticsModule.m file for ios, and params Bundle in UniversalFirebaseAnalyticsModule.java for android, for logEvent method. For ios it was sending NSString instead of NSNumber, and for android, it was double, instead of long.